# How to test exceptions using MockMvc?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am stubbing a void method and testing for returned status.
ControllerTest:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(UserControllerRest.class)
class UserControllerRestTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    @DisplayName("Will return a 409 conflict.")
    @Test
    void createExistingUser() throws Exception {
        User testUser = userList.get("superman");
        // Also tried willThrow() as given in the BDDMockito javadoc
        doThrow(new UserExistsException("User with id: "+testUser.getId()+" already exists."))
                .when(userService).createUser(testUser);
        this.mockMvc.perform(post("/user")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                .content(mapper.writeValueAsString(testUser)))
                .andExpect(status().isConflict())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.message", is("User with id "+testUser.getId()+" exists.")));
    }

}
```

My controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserControllerRest {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(value = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity createUser(@RequestBody final User user){
        try {
            userService.createUser(user);
            return genericResponseSupplier.apply("User created", HttpStatus.CREATED);
        }
        catch (Exception ge){
            logger.error("Exception creating new user: ");
            ge.printStackTrace();

            if (ge.getClass().equals(UserExistsException.class) )
                return genericErrorResponseSupplier.apply("User already exists.", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);

            return serverErrorResponse.get();

        }
    }
}
```

No matter what I try, the test fails because it always returns 200.
I can't think of what else to try. What am I missing?

Comment: Is your `User` class overriding `equals` and `hashCode`? Is `new User().equals(new User())` true?

Comment: No. I'm not overriding those.

Comment: Then how do you think that Mockito would be able to determine that your `when` call is handling the object when it cannot compare the objects?